# SQL Statement using Between

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am attempting to write a query to get `ename` as "Employee Name" with the first letter capitalized and `deptno` as "Department No", limiting to employees whose second character of their name is between A and M.

This is the query I have so far which isn't working:

```
select initcap(ename) "Employee Name", deptno "Department No" 
from emp 
where ename between '_A%' and '_M%';
```

Result: no rows selected.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. You should remove things that are not important to the question. It seems that you're issue is with using `between` but there's a lot more in your query that is unrelated to that.

Comment: `ename` when it's being evaluated in your `WHERE` clause does not have the `initcap` applied to it. It's just as it is in your data. Perhaps `WHERE ename between '_a%' AND '_m%';` would work? That probably won't work though since `BETWEEN` doesn't support the use of wildcards. So you probably need something like `REGEXP_LIKE()` to pull this off. Perhaps if you share some sample `ename` data someone can whip that up for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an Oracle admin, so I'm not very familiar with [its `BETWEEN` conditionals](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions011.htm), but in general SQL `BETWEEN` is used for single values such as integers.

For example `BETWEEN 1 AND 100` will match an integer value of 50, but not 150.

I suspect that your query is doing the same thing, looking for string values that are in the sequence between the two strings you provided.

The strings you provided seem to be the type used with [`LIKE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions007.htm#SQLRF52122), and I would not expect them to work here.

I would instead use a regular expression to match for a range of values like this. The [`REGEXP_LIKE` condition](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions007.htm#SQLRF00501) will allow you to do that:

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(ename, '^.[a-m]', 'i')
```

This is a fairly simple regular expression, matching only from the beginning of the string (`^`), allowing any character in the first position (`.`), followed by a character in the range (`[a-m]`). The `'i'` parameter makes the expression case-insensitive.